# React Native: How to make app programatically refresh when signing in or out?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

My app uses Expo and React Native. I have implemented authentication using Firebase.

My problem is that when I sign in or out the navigation stack should change but it does not refresh. The only way is if I make a code change and Expo implements fast refresh. The console logs do print when the auth state is changed but for some reason the NavigationContainer does not change. Is there anyway that I can programatically create a fast refresh?

Here is my code:

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacityComponent, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AuthStackScreen from './screens/AuthStack/AuthStackScreen';
import AppStackScreen from './screens/AppStack/AppStackScreen';
import Firebase from './firebase/Firebase';


const App = () => {
  let loggedIn;

  if(Firebase.auth().currentUser) {
    loggedIn = true;
  }

  Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user) {
      loggedIn = true;
      console.log("logged in")
    } else {
      loggedIn = false;
      console.log("logged out")
    }
  })

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      { loggedIn ? <AppStackScreen/> : <AuthStackScreen/> }
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
  
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are willing to re-render your component.
The thing which satisfies your need is [Hooks](https://medium.com/@guptagaruda/react-hooks-understanding-component-re-renders-9708ddee9928).

basically you should convert your

```
 let loggedIn;
```

into

```
 const [loggedIn,setLoggedIn]=useState(false)
      if(Firebase.auth().currentUser) {
         setLoggedIn(true)
       }
      Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
         if(user) {
           setLoggedIn(true)
           console.log("logged in")
         } else {
           setLoggedIn(false)
           console.log("logged out")
         }
       })
```